# createAnswer format mediaConstraints - convertDartToNative_Dictionary

Tags: dart, webrtc

Have a working webrtc app written in js, now try to port it to dart. Are stuck on format, when setting media constrains for createAnswer.
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-html/RtcPeerConnection/createAnswer.html

In js the working media constrain is:

```
var mediaConstraints = {
  optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}],
  mandatory: {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: false,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: false
  }
};
```

With dart `createAnswer` mediaContraints are converted with `convertDartToNative_Dictionary`. I have tried various different formats, but stuck with `Error: OperationError: Malformed constraints object.` from `js_helper.dart:1772`.

Have in dart tried e.g.

```
Map mediaConstraints = {
  "optional" : [{"RtpDataChannels" : true}],
  "mandatory" : {
    "OfferToReceiveAudio" : false,
    "OfferToReceiveVideo" : false
  }
};
```

Basically something converted with `convertDartToNative_Dictionary` 
 that matches the js object above is needed. Easy to test, so even loose tips are welcome.

Comment: Is this is in Dartium or compiled to JavaScript?

It is likely the former doesn't work, and unfortunately is not longer supported.

Comment: This is compiled to JavaScript, same for compiled with dart2js or dartdevc.